# wget downloads in a loop

Tags: wget

I am trying to download some files using:

```
$ for i in `seq 1234 1250`;
  do
    torify wget -A.mp4 http://www.my_example.com/video.php?id=$i&dl=1

  done
```

Clearly these all downloads will be started simultaneously. How can I dowmload one by one. Though I am not sure but I think that wget exit successfully with a exit status of 8 but am unable to come up with the appropriate `if` or `while/untill` statements.

Would somebody help??

Answer (score 0):

You've fallen afoul of shell special characters. With shell quoting, the line:

```
torify wget -A.mp4 http://www.my_example.com/video.php?id=$i&dl=1
```

becomes:

```
torify wget -A.mp4 http://www.my_example.com/video.php\?id=$i\&dl=1
```

which will NOT go into the background, and will execute one at a time.